# Deploy no heroku depois de reinstalar o Ubuntu

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-boot, heroku

Boa tarde!
Eu precisei reinstalar o Ubuntu na minha máquina, e era por ela que eu fazia o deploy para o heroku. Mas agora que já reinstalei tudo eu não consigo mais fazer o deploy.

Eu clonei o projeto do git e consigo fazer o push para o repositório remoto do gitlab tranquilo, mas para o heroku não. A aplicação já está criada no heroku e tudo configurado. Eu tenho que clonar do repositório do heroku?

Comment: você já tem instalado o heroku cli? na maquina? para clonar tem que acessar a conta do heroku e pega o link da aplicação do heroku. exemplo heroku git:clone -a codisistem

Comment: Boa tarde! Já tenho o Heroku CLI instalado sim. Eu tentei clonar o projeto do jeito que você sugeriu, mas retorna o seguinte erro:  ▸    ENOENT: spawn git ENOENT

Comment: @MardonisAlvesBezerra eu já tentei até mesmo atualizar a chave ssh, mas também da error. Mas eu consigo fazer o login e até mesmo criar outro app usando o comando heroku create.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema removendo o Heroku e instalando novamente pelo repositório, seguindo este tutorial ->  [instalar heroku pelo repositório](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/heroku/8324/command-line/26715/download-and-install#t=201707101220011633055)

Depois é só gerar a chave ssh `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, fazer o login no heroku com o comando `heroku login`, por final, enviar a chave que foi gerada anteriormente `heroku keys:add`.

[Como gerar a chave SSH e fazer o uploud para o heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys)

Obs: Para quem instalou o Heroku com o snap, basta usar o comando`sudo snap remove heroku`.